# How can I change the Title from a Usercontrol in another cs?

Tags: c#, user-controls, title

I have made a UserControl button named UserControl1, and I am trying to change its title from the templates where I am copying it (much like the easy clock-devise but one little step ahead).

I can not seem to do it. I write this code in the UserControl1, :

```
    public string Display
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
        set { label1.Text = value; }
    }
```

Then, I write this in the form, within the public class:

```
UserControl1.Display = "Title";
```

It shows an error at the "=" sign:

> Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.

I have a feeling im really close, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a code like this...

```
class someClass
{
    UserControl1.Display = "Title";
}
```

You cannot directly put your code inside a class like this, you have to create a method and then write this code inside that. For ex, change your code as below...

```
class someClass
{
   UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
   public void some_Method()
    {
        uc.Display = "Title";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if I create another public void like that, for example: 

public void Displaystring() { UserControl1.Display = "Title"; } 

I get another error: 

Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: The error is in the UserControl1.Display, it is asking for an object reference.

Comment: @Benoo888 I think you have to create an instance of the UserControl in your current page. `UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1(); Now you can write uc.Display = "Title".`

Comment: Thank you! Your solution was correct. The only problem I had was that my form renamed my UserControl1 to UserControl11, now it works like sunshine!